# Laravel 5.2 - PHPunit - How to send email to support team if test has failed?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I want to know how I can send email to the support team if one of my unitest has failed?

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
         $this->visit('/login')->see('Hello');
    }
}
```

How I can send an email if this test has failed?

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your `phpunit` command in another script that will send the report of PHP unit if the return code is not 0.

Actually you could create a custom artisan command that will run `phpunit`, take the output, and use `Mail` facade to send the report. AFAIK phpunit doesn't have this feature out-of-the-box

**EDIT** code example:

```
public function handle()
{
    $command = new Process("vendor/bin/phpunit");
    $command->run();
    $this->info($command->getIncrementalOutput());
    if($command->isSuccessful()) {
      // do your stuff    
    }
    // do other stuff
}
```